# How to find out the status of war deployment in springDm?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, osgi, war, spring-dm

I am trying to do junit testing using maven based surefire testing and  AbstractConfigurableBundleCreatorTests class for springDM based web application.

How to know if the war bundle is Successfully deployed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could probably utilise the [BundleListener](http://www.osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleListener.html) somehow to listen to the status of your bundle. add the listener to the bundleContext.

Comment: I tried that one. The state is active of war bundle even if it is not deployed. In the log file i found this event INFO org.springframework.osgi.web.deployer.tomcat.TomcatWarDeployer - Successfully deployed bundle. If i could access this event..